# Changing one part of a CSS class

Tags: html, css

I have made some container classes in CSS which are quite large. One of my divs uses this container class, however I would like to change the padding from 10px; to 0px;. I do not want to create a whole new class for this. What is the most efficient way to do this?

An example of my div in html

```
<div class="my-container">
</div>
```

An example of my container class

```
.my-container
{
   lots of fields...
   padding:10px;
}
```

An example of what I want without creating a new class

```
.my-container
{
   lots of fields...
   padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: *I do not want to create a whole new class for this.* Are you saying this because you don't want to have to repeat everything in "lots of fields" for your new class? Because you can use a new class without having to repeat everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new class with one line inherit .my-container, like this:

```css
.my-container{
   border: 1px solid blue;
   background: red;
   margin: 10px 0;
   padding:10px;
}
.my-container.no-padding{
   padding:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">my-container
</div>
<div class="my-container">my-container
</div>
<div class="my-container no-padding">my-no-padding-container
</div>
<div class="my-container">my-container
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was efficient and works well. Great.